# Find out centre of the most dense region in a scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a set of x and y coordinates. I want to plot them and find out which region is densely plotted. I want to find the coordinates of the centre of that region.

I have written a code for plotting the points in x-y plane.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([111,152,153,14,155,156,153,154,153,152,154,151,200,201,200])
y = np.array([112,151,153,12,153,154,155,153,152,153,152,153,202,202,204])
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, I'm not able to find out the centre of the densely plotted region. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Define "dense" first - what region/neighborhood would you include to calculate density of an area, and what is an area? You could add a gaussian around each point and find the maximum of the resulting function - but you'd have to pick an appropriate radius first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you need to distinguish between (and be certain about) *density* and *clustering*. Your question does not clearly define what you desire, so I assume that you want to assess the location among your points where the *maximum density* is found. To be honest, I was up for some refreshing task and thus picked the *density* option here ;)

The term density alone is underspecified as there are manifold ways to assess/estimate/calculate a point cloud density. I suggest to use a KDE (kernel density estimator) as it is quite easy to be fitted to one's needs and allows to exchange kernels (square, linear, Gaussian, Cosine, and whatever else that is applicable).

**Note:** Full code below; I'll go through it stepwise with smaller snippets now.

### Preliminaries

Starting with the points you provided, the following snippet calculates a proper evenly-spaced grid in your Cartesian coordinates:

```
RESOLUTION = 50
LOCALITY = 2.0

dx = max(pts_x) - min(pts_x)
dy = max(pts_y) - min(pts_y)

delta = min(dx, dy) / RESOLUTION
nx = int(dx / delta)
ny = int(dy / delta)
radius = (1 / LOCALITY) * min(dx, dy)

grid_x = np.linspace(min(pts_x), max(pts_x), num=nx)
grid_y = np.linspace(min(pts_y), max(pts_y), num=ny)

x, y = np.meshgrid(grid_x, grid_y)
```

You can easily check it by plotting `plt.scatter(grid_x, grid_y)`, if you like. All these preliminary calculations just make sure to have all required values at hand: I want to be able to specify some kind of *resolution* and a *locality* setting for the KDE kernel spread; furthermore we need the maximum point distances in `x` and `y` direction for grid generation, calculate the step size `delta`, calculate the number of grid cells in x and y directions, `nx` and `ny`, respectively, as well as calculate the kernel `radius` according to our locality setting.

### Kernel Density Estimation

For estimating the point density using a kernel, we do need two functions as outlined in the next snippet

```
def gauss(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    """
    Apply a Gaussian kernel estimation (2-sigma) to distance between points.

    Effectively, this applies a Gaussian kernel with a fixed radius to one
    of the points and evaluates it at the value of the euclidean distance
    between the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).
    The Gaussian is transformed to roughly (!) yield 1.0 for distance 0 and
    have the 2-sigma located at radius distance.
    """
    return (
        (1.0 / (2.0 * math.pi))
        * math.exp(
            -1 * (3.0 * math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2) / radius))**2
        / 0.4)


def _kde(x, y):
    """
    Estimate the kernel density at a given position.

    Simply sums up all the Gaussian kernel values towards all points
    (pts_x, pts_y) from position (x, y).
    """
    return sum([
        gauss(x, px, y, py)
        # math.sqrt((x - px)**2 + (y - py)**2)
        for px, py in zip(pts_x, pts_y)
    ])
```

The first one, `gauss` performs two tasks at once: It takes two points defined by `x1, x2, y1, y2`, calculates their Euclidean distance and uses that distance to assess a Gauss kernel's function value. The Gauss kernel is transformed to approximately yield `1.0` when the distance is `0` (or *very* small), and to have its 2-sigma fixed at the previously calculated `radius`. This characteristic is controlled by the above mentioned `locality` setting.

### Identifying the Maximum

Luckily, `numpy` provides some neat helper functions to apply arbitrary Python functions to vectors and matrices, so the calculation is as easy as:

```
kde = np.vectorize(_kde)  # Let numpy care for applying our kde to a vector
z = kde(x, y)

xi, yi = np.where(z == np.amax(z))
max_x = grid_x[xi][0]
max_y = grid_y[yi][0]
print(f"{max_x:.4f}, {max_y:.4f}")
```

In your case (given the Gaussian kernel settings and my grid assumptions), the maximum density is at

```
155.2041, 154.0800
```

### Plotting

Your point cloud (blue crosses) with the identified maximum (red cross) is shown in the first picture. The second picture shows the estimated density as calculated by the Gaussian KDE using the settings as in the first code snippet.

[image: point cloud and maximum density location]

[image: kernel density estimation]

### Full Code

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pts_x = np.array([
    111, 152, 153, 14, 155, 156, 153, 154, 153, 152, 154, 151, 200, 201, 200])
pts_y = np.array([
    112, 151, 153, 12, 153, 154, 155, 153, 152, 153, 152, 153, 202, 202, 204])


RESOLUTION = 50
LOCALITY = 2.0

dx = max(pts_x) - min(pts_x)
dy = max(pts_y) - min(pts_y)

delta = min(dx, dy) / RESOLUTION
nx = int(dx / delta)
ny = int(dy / delta)
radius = (1 / LOCALITY) * min(dx, dy)

grid_x = np.linspace(min(pts_x), max(pts_x), num=nx)
grid_y = np.linspace(min(pts_y), max(pts_y), num=ny)

x, y = np.meshgrid(grid_x, grid_y)


def gauss(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    """
    Apply a Gaussian kernel estimation (2-sigma) to distance between points.

    Effectively, this applies a Gaussian kernel with a fixed radius to one
    of the points and evaluates it at the value of the euclidean distance
    between the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).
    The Gaussian is transformed to roughly (!) yield 1.0 for distance 0 and
    have the 2-sigma located at radius distance.
    """
    return (
        (1.0 / (2.0 * math.pi))
        * math.exp(
            -1 * (3.0 * math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2) / radius))**2
        / 0.4)


def _kde(x, y):
    """
    Estimate the kernel density at a given position.

    Simply sums up all the Gaussian kernel values towards all points
    (pts_x, pts_y) from position (x, y).
    """
    return sum([
        gauss(x, px, y, py)
        # math.sqrt((x - px)**2 + (y - py)**2)
        for px, py in zip(pts_x, pts_y)
    ])


kde = np.vectorize(_kde)  # Let numpy care for applying our kde to a vector
z = kde(x, y)

xi, yi = np.where(z == np.amax(z))
max_x = grid_x[xi][0]
max_y = grid_y[yi][0]
print(f"{max_x:.4f}, {max_y:.4f}")


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='inferno', vmin=np.min(z), vmax=np.max(z))
fig.set_size_inches(4, 4)
fig.savefig('density.png', bbox_inches='tight')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(pts_x, pts_y, marker='+', color='blue')
ax.scatter(grid_x[xi], grid_y[yi], marker='+', color='red', s=200)
fig.set_size_inches(4, 4)
fig.savefig('marked.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Great stuff, why it was not approved?!

Comment: There seems to be some mixup in the meshgrid index ordering, you should be using `np.meshgrid(grid_x, grid_y, indexing='ij')`, or else you get your indices backwards. It's not apparent in your example, because these example points are basically on a line.

Comment: Additionally, `np.vectorize` doesn't work well here, you can have huge speedup by writing native vectorized ops. Switch `math.` ops to `np.`, then, `def kde(x, y): return gauss(x[:,:,None], pts_x, y[:,:,None], pts_y).sum(axis=-1)`